# How to extract an argument value from an existing Pyinstaller .spec file?

Tags: python, parsing, pyinstaller

Suppose, for some obscure reason, we need to determine the values of some input arguments that are *hardcoded* into an *existing* PyInstaller `.spec` file, without actually running PyInstaller.

For example, we would like to extract the values of the `name` arguments in the simplified example below.

How could that be done?

```py
...
a = Analysis(['path/to/my/script.py'], pathex=[], ...)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,a.scripts, [], exclude_binaries=True, name='my_exe_name', ...)
coll = COLLECT(exe, a.binaries, a.zipfiles, ..., name='my_output_dir_name')
...
```

My initial thought would be to read the file content as text, then parse it, e.g. looking for `"name="`. However, that feels fragile.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach that appears to work well:

This uses [unittest.mock.Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) to replace the PyInstaller classes, such as [Analysis](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/v4.9/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py), and then uses [runpy.run_path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_path) to run the spec file.

The `Mock` instances remember the arguments they were called with.

```py
from runpy import run_path
from unittest.mock import Mock

# run the .spec file with mocked PyInstaller classes
mocks = dict(Analysis=Mock(), EXE=Mock(), PYZ=Mock(), COLLECT=Mock())
run_path(path_name="path/to/my.spec", init_globals=mocks)

# extract any desired input arg or kwarg from the Mock instances
exe_name = mocks["EXE"].call_args.kwargs["name"]  # 'my_exe_name'
output_dir_name = mocks["COLLECT"].call_args.kwargs["name"]  # 'my_output_dir_name'
...
```